# Zip up directory before S3 bucket deployment

Tags: aws-cdk

I have a typescript CDK package where I need to upload a directory to S3 - I'd like the directory to be zipped up by the CDK code - is there any way to specify the directory should be zipped in the `BucketDeployment` before uploading to S3?

```
    new s3Deploy.BucketDeployment(this, 'bucket-code-deployment', {
        sources: [s3Deploy.Source.asset('../infra/lambdas/lambda/directory')],
        destinationBucket: lambdaCodeBucket,
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can zip a directory using the Asset class

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_s3_assets.Asset.html

```js
const bundle = new Asset(this, 'bundle', {
  path: 'src/resources/dockerExample',
});
```

An example of it being used here: https://subaud.io/blog/cdk-deployment-of-docker-image-with-codebuild